# Verizon HTC Trophy 7.8 update

Tags: 7.5

My HTC Trophy has yet to received the 7.8 update. Is there anyway to force an update?

If it helps, my carrier is Verizon .

Answer (score 4):

You can't do much officially if your carrier hasn't pushed it out. But you can unofficially flash the official update with a tool called [Sharp7Eighter](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2261514) (or its '[improved](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2202393)' version) which allows you to update to Windows Phone 7.8. They claim that:

> Every single Windows Phone is supported, no matter the carrier nor the manufacturer (although there appears to be issues with "Walshed" phones)

Searching the forum shows that someone seems to have an issue with the Verizon Trophy, so it may or may not work for you.

As it is unofficial, there is a chance of **bricking** your phone. So I would suggest doing some research before deciding to attempt this.

Comment: The last I heard, 7.8 would be released for all the end of the first quarter...it's the end of May and I haven't heard a peep.

Comment: It's been out since February but HTC seem to be pretty bad at releasing the updates, HTC don't even list the Trophy on their site any more.